# Elasticsearch mapping

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mapping

How to change mapping in existing index of elasticsearch? I need set type for location on geo_point type.

```
{
    "stations": {
        "mappings": {
            "station": {
                "properties": {
                    "address": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "district": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "properties": {
                            "lat": {
                                "type": "double"
                            },
                            "lon": {
                                "type": "double"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This [article](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime/) explains several approaches to this problem. Types can not be explicitly changed on an existing field.

Answer (score 1):

To apply new mapping you need to reindex the data.If you add new field its no problem , no need to reindex data.

**To delete existing index**

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/index/type/_mapping"
```

**To add geo point type**

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/index/type/_mapping" -d'
{
    "stations": {
        "mappings": {
            "station": {
                "properties": {
                    "address": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "district": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

use above curl command to create new mapping to index. for more info refer [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html)

Comment: here can you please tell me what is stations and station is it the index/type or what ??? please reply ??

Comment: stations is index and station is type.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a template index with the mapping that you want and update the mapping (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html)

Supposing your index name is something like "myindex". You can create a mapping by running:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_template/myindex_template_1" -d'
{
  "template": "myindex*",
  "mappings" : {
    "stations": {
        "mappings": {
            "station": {
                "properties": {
                    "address": {
                       "type": "string"
                    },
                    "district": {
                       "type": "string"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

This allows you to create new indices that start with the prefix "myindex" with the new mapping. The next step is read from the existing index to the new index using a tool such as Logstash.

Create a config file (e.g. reindex.conf) like the example (update with your settings):

```
input {
      elasticsearch {

          hosts => ["localhost"] # Update with your server hostname here
          scan => true
          scroll => "5m"
          index => "myindex"  #update with your existing index name
          docinfo => true
      }
}

output {
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
       elasticsearch {
          host => "localhost"
          protocol => "http"
          index => "myindex2" # notice I created a new index name
          document_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
          document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
       }
}
```

After that, you can delete the old index and create an alias to the new index so that your application can still refer to it using the old index name. Example:

```
curl -X DELETE localhost:9200/myindex

curl -X POST localhost:9200/_aliases -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "myindex2", "alias" : "myindex" } }
    ]
}'
```

If you ever create a myindex3 for example, you can just do:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "myindex2", "alias" : "myindex" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "myindex3", "alias" : "myindex" } }
    ]
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing the type of a field in the existing mapping. I would suggest you to send the ignore_conflicts parameter.

curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/mapped-index/article/_mapping?ignore_conflicts=true" -d '{"article":{"properties":{"body":{"type":"geo_point
"}}}}'